# Rails carrierwave Images not showing up

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

All the images have `hidden` tag and `display: none;` by default

The html code for images after uploading:

`<img src="/uploads/ad/image/6/thumb_95adae32e516d173eb84c081c5629f5d.png" hidden="" style="display: none !important;">`

index.html.erb (code for images):

```
   <%= link_to image_tag(ad.image_url(:thumb)), ad %>
```

new.html.erb:

```
    <%= f.file_field :image %>
```

image_uploader.rb code:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
   include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  storage :file
  # storage :fog

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

   version :thumb do
     process resize_to_fit: [400, 300]
   end

   version :default do
    process resize_to_fit: [800, 600]
    end

   def extension_whitelist
     %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
   end

end
```

ad.rb:

```
    mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
```

add_image_to_ad migration:

```
class AddImageToAds < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_column :ads, :image, :string
  end
end
```

ads_controller.rb:

```
 def ad_params
      params.require(:ad).permit(:brand, :condition, :title, :description, :price, :image)
 end
```

Comment: Do you have any javascipt that could be messing with your images setting that style? Check the browser network tab and verify if the original HTML (the original request response) has or doesn't has that hidden style. If it's not hidden at first then some javascript is hidding them.

Comment: @arieljuod Thanks, the javascript was hidding the image